# App Memory Consumption

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have been playing with optimizing my app, and I see that there are some general ideas on how much memory it should use... I'm running between 70-80Mb right now, is that a crazy number or just a little on the heavy side?

My second question is about the memory I am using. About 42Mb is taken up by graphics, whether I run the app with the layout graphics or run it without setting any views... any ideas on where to look? I feel like it is the theme, but I am not sure how to test that.

I've been searching for days to figure out why it uses so much and cannot figure it out. It remains constant regardless of which activity I am on, any ideas are welcome!

UPDATE:

- I ended up running it on an emulator and got about 26Mb, more what I was expecting, but it runs at 70Mb with the 42Mb of graphics on the actual device.
- The emulator allows for a 384Mb app after getting memoryclass information, while the device only allows 256Mb... the emulator has more storage and runs more efficiently.
- The emulator is Android 8.1 27api while the device is Android 7.0 24api.
- Tried on an older Android 5.1.1 api 22 below also.

Any ideas?

I have another question with about why the emulators have a such a difference in performance here if you know the answer on that, but I wanted to keep these questions separate: [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622841/android-studio-emulator-profile-different-than-device-profile)

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has an awesome tool called [Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler). It helps you analyze possible memory leaks and see which calls are using up the most memory. You can even pause the processor and 'zoom in' to deep dive on the call stack.

Comment: I've been trying to play with it, but haven't entirely figured out where the calls are coming from yet. I will post a couple pictures to see if you guys can see anything, but I have been looking for good resources on how to read it better. From what I am seeing though, the calls seem to recurse into themselves for many levels...

Comment: It sounds like you have a memory leak. Try scrolling in and out to go to higher level calls and see where it starts to find the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, I've been testing on a 24api device that restricts some new features in Android Studio (app uses a lot of bluetooth functions that kill the emulators), but I guess I can kill those for now to try to find this. It is just weird though, the memory remains the exact same no matter how long it runs and doesn't change... 42.2Mb for hours lol

Comment: Ok, I found something interesting... The emulator running the same package holds at 26Mb with no graphics while the actual device runs at 68Mb with 42 Mb of graphics, any ideas on that? Lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**LeakCanary**](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) A memory leak detection library for Android and Java. Maintain by Square. This is one of the best developer's Tool for memory optimization and detecting leaks.[here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

Comment: I've been playing with it for a little, and nothing comes up with LeakCanary either, its crazy!

Comment: Yeah its crazy ,But Then You can always refer Official Documentation here [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory) maybe it can give new Ideas or can trigger different ways for you to approach Memory optimization .

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at it a few times and can definitely improve some things down the road... More interesting is that it runs as expected on the emulator with 0Mb of graphics... Between 10-20Mb total

Comment: I have some screenshots of it in the other linked question... Haven't seen anyone else asking about it yet