# Android Studio - Emulator Profile and Device Profile VERY different

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I came across this while asking a different question, why does the Android Emulator show such a different performance profile than a comparable device profile?

Specifically, the device calls a huge graphics section that is not visible on the emulator... is there a reason for this?

Device - 26api - 48Mb
[image: device 26api]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 26api - 24Mb - Hardware Graphics
[image: 26api]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 26api - 54Mb - Software Graphics
[image: 26api]

Device - 24api - 52Mb
[image: device]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 24api - Hardware Graphics - 15Mb
[image: pixel2]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 24api - Software Graphics - 40Mb
[image: pixel2 software]

Device - 22Api - 50Mb
[image: device2]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 22api - Hardware Graphics - 14Mb
[image: pixel2 22]

Emulator (Pixel2) - 22api - Software Graphics - 40Mb
[image: pixel2 22]

Answer (score 1):

This depend on how your configure `Emulator` if you a good amount of `RAM` with `HAXM`.

This can improve your performance app have less `System.gc()` if `Emulator` `RAM` is more than `Device`.

But is not the only things and you can configure your `HAXM` acceleration [HAXM acceleration Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm).

**Explaination**

`Without acceleration, the emulator takes the machine code from the VM and translates it block by block to conform to the architecture of the host computer. This process can be quite slow. But, if the VM and the architecture of the host computer match (such as x86 on x86), the emulator can skip translating the code and simply run it directly on the actual CPU using a hypervisor. In this case, the emulator can approach the speed of the host computer.`

**Explaination 2**

`When you create an Android Virtual Device (AVD) in the AVD Manager, you can specify that graphics acceleration occur in hardware or software to emulate the GPU of the virtual device. Hardware acceleration is typically faster. Software acceleration is useful if your computer uses graphics drivers that aren't compatible with the emulator, in which case hardware graphics rendering can be poor or cause the emulator to crash.`

`The default is to let the emulator decide if it should use hardware or software graphics acceleration based on your computer setup. If the GPU hardware and drivers are compatible, the emulator uses the GPU; otherwise, the emulator uses the CPU to simulate GPU processing.`

`Graphics: Memory used for graphics buffer queues to display pixels to the screen, including GL surfaces, GL textures, and so on. (Note that this is memory shared with the CPU, not dedicated GPU memory.)`

[View the Java heap and memory allocations with Memory Profiler Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)

So why your `Graphic use` is to `0Mb` is because the `Memory Profiler` calculating the memory shared between `CPU` and `GPU` not dedicated to `GPU`.

So is 0Mb because you use `hardware` I think instead of `software to emulate the GPU`.

Comment: Yeah, I will have to check it. I know that the emulator gives a memory class of 384Mb for the app, while the device gives 256Mb, but why would that cause 0Mb of graphics memory compared to 40Mb of Memory on the device?

Comment: I think this can explain why is 0Mb of graphic. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Comment: I'll try switching it around and post the results!

Comment: It could definitely be that, I posted some interesting comparisons to look at more as well